# How to convert Kilo Units (KU) to mg?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, neuroscience, bioinformatics, proteins

Im searching for AChE (Acetylcholinesterase) and on sigma-aldrich it is showing 2 KU or 2000U/mg of protein and on MedChemExpress it is showing 50mg then how can we calcute how much will be the drug in the Sigma product

Comment: Would be easier to help if you provide the links to these pages. Sigma should also mention the actual quantity (ug) near where the price is. I assume that's what you are looking for?

- There is no conversion from Units to mg. units are a measurement of enzyme activity, generally reported normalized to mass as units/mg

Comment: Have a look at the sigma product  - it should have the mass or the number of units. Simple conversion from mass to units using the provided info.